# jqChart date labels display only time

Tags: jquery, charts, jqchart

I’m creating a zoomable chart with jqChart. I’m using the code from this sample:

http://www.jqchart.com/samples

The issue is when I’m zooming the chart a lot, the x-axis labels switch form dates to times.

How can I display the real date (not only time) when zoom?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The jqChart axis labels are formatted depending on the date time interval, which is calculated. If interval becomes ‘hours’ it changes the labels string format.

You can change the string format with:

```
axes: [ 
       { 
          type: 'dateTime', 
          location: 'bottom', 
          labels: { stringFormat: 'm/d/yy' }
      } 
     ]
```

and in this case the labels won’t turn to a time.

More about the labels formatting you can find here:

http://www.jqchart.com/documentation/userguide/default.aspx#!LabelsFormatting

Answer (score 1):

Hi you can specify the ***intervalType*** in the ***dateTimeAxisOptions*** when you construct the chart

[here](http://www.jqchart.com/documentation/userguide/default.aspx#!DateTimeAxis) is the documentation and you can do something like this, this should solve your peoblem

```
axes: [
    {
          type: 'dateTime',
          location: 'bottom',
          minimum: new Date(2011, 1, 4),
          maximum: new Date(2011, 1, 18),
          interval: 1,
          intervalType: 'days'
      }
   ]
```